Creating a virtual environment with pycharm: get some package I do not need
I'm programming with Python and I'm working with PyCharm Community 2024.1 IDE under Linux Debian 10 (buster).
When I create a new project with a new virtual environment I get some packages despite I do not activate the "Inherite pakages from base interpreter" checkbox.
To create the new project I do:
New Project -> I specify the name of the project and the project path -> click on Custom environment -> click on radio button "Generate new" ->  Select "Virtualenv" as Type -> select the interpreter (/usr/local/python3.9) -> select the venv location (same as the project path).
I do not activate "Inherite pakages from base interpreter"
I do not activate "Make available to all projectsd".
Then I click create.
It takes about 20s to create the project.
Now, if I take a look to: File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter
I can see some packages already installed, there are about 100 packages.
I thought that when we create a new project with a new venv, it was normally empty.
After a short look at the list, it seems that these packages are correlate to ROS packages installed on my system. But I do not know why they appear in my new venv.
If I check the box "Inherite pakages from base interpreter" I get the same result.
Do you have any idea ?
Thank you very much.

What are ROS packages? What are the 100 packages installed? And finally are you sure you are looking at your newly created environment? You say you are looking at the python interpreter for the project, but does the project have the right python interpreter?

Hello, ROS packages are python package I have intalled months ago. They are intended to work on robotic.

If I check in the Python Interpreter I can see that the interpreter seems to be the good one: Python 3.9 (pythonProject1), which is the name of the venv I have created.

For information, I have launched PyCharm in sudo mode, and when creating a new project the same way, the list of the installed package is, in this case, empty, appart from pip, setuptools and wheel which are present.

Hi all, do you think it is a bug from PyCharm ? Am I making a mistake ? Thank you very much.

It does seem like a bug. I would advise just to create a virtual environment in your project without pycharm. It should only take a moment.  https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html PyCharm should find it if is already there. (also don't run PyCharm in sudo mode)

Hello, I will do that. Thanks a lot for your recomandation.

Hello Topsail, I have followed your recommendation and it works perfectly this way. Thank you very much. It seems that there is a Pycharm bug.
